# Enque a javascript when a shortocode is call in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call/add/enque a javascript file when a shortcode is executed.

Below is my code, please let me know what is wrong i am doing.

```
add_shortcode('footprint', 'do_footprint');

function do_footprint()
{   
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pace_enque_map_scripts' );

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

function pace_enque_map_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}
```

When i call the action hook to  add javascript directly it works. But when i call the action hook with in a function it doesn't works.

Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
function do_footprint() { 
    ob_start(); ?>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('footprint', 'do_footprint');

function pace_enque_map_scripts() {
    global $post;
    //check shortcode existence in post content and enque script if found
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'footprint') && !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pace_enque_map_scripts');
```